# Are SAT scores considered discrete? If so, then can we use the normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, soft-question

I believe the definition of a normal distribution only applies to continous random variables. But SAT scores are normally distributed and the possible values of an SAT score are discrete.

Comment: The normal distribution only [opproximates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) the scores distribution.

Answer (score 1):

SAT scores are certainly not normally distributed.  Besides being discrete, they are restricted to a finite range.  However, it is possible that for some purposes you can treat the normal distribution as a good approximation to the actual distribution.

Comment: The range is not only finite, it is also non negative. Unlike the normal distribution.

Comment: Actually the range (for all three sections combined) is $[600, 2400]$.

Comment: Actually, the range is [0,2400], since there is a -0.25 points for every wrong multiple-choice question. Thus, if a person gets every question wrong, the final score is a zero. However, I don't see how anyone can score that low in real life, so it is a hypothetical range.